# Different estimates from 2SRI and fixed effects regression. is this endogeneity?

Tags: cost-functions, fixed-effects, endogeneity

I am comparing two different models to resolve potential endogeneity concerns in my empirical models. First, I ran fixed-effects models without handling any endogeneity concerns, and I got significant results that support my hypotheses.

However, since independent variables are theoretically believed that they may suffer from endogeneity issues, I also performed a two stage residual inclusion approach using instrumental variables. According to the estimates of the residuals from the first stage (insignificance means no serious endogeneity) and DWH test of endogeneity, they all say that my models do not suffer from endogeneity.

At this point, one thing that I am a bit worried about is that there are quite noticeable differences between the estimates of fixed-effects models (without considering endogeneity issues) and 2SRI models. Does this indicate that my models still need to resolve endogeneity issues even if both Durbin-Wu-Hausman test of endogeneity (when using 2sls) and estimates of residuals in the second stage of 2SRI do not say that my model has endogeneity?

Thank you in advance.